# reach the last line with end of line in java

Tags: java

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = "";
String pera = " ";

System.out.println("Enter the text : ");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(isr);
int lineNum = 0;
do {
    line = buf.readLine();
    System.out.println();
    pera = line + "";
    lineNum++;
    System.out.print(lineNum + " " + pera);
} while (line != null);
isr.close();
buf.close();
```

input : 
Hello world
I am a file
Read me until end-of-file.

output : 
1 Hello world
2 I am a file
3 Read me until end-of-file.

and this code output is : 
1 Hello world
2 I am a file
3 Read me until end-of-file.
4 null

Comment: This question blinds me!!! By the horrible spelling.

Comment: I am not sure what you want, if you want to remove the null, Replace do while with while((line = buf.readLine()) != null){sop; pera = ...; sop(++lineNum+""+pera)}

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify things. You can assign a variable in a while loop. Read lines one by one in it until it comes to end. We understand this when the `BufferedReader` reads a null line using `(line = br.readLine()) != null`.

```
System.out.println("Enter the text: ");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
int lineNo = 0;
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(++lineNo + " " + line);
}
isr.close();
br.close();
```